# Ubuntu search dash located out of the display

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

Dash (launched with 'super') is located out of the display (on the bottom of the screen) and it's impossible to see the result. Any idea?

This happens both when two monitors are connected or only one.

[image: cropped image of display bottom]